# r shiny - uiOutput not rendering inside menuItem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

**Question**

Why does a `sliderInput()` that's generated on the `server`, and rendered on the `ui` with `uiOutput()` not get displayed in a `menuItem()`?

**Example**

In this simple app I'm generating a `sliderInput` on the `server` (note the `menuItem` is deliberately commented out), and it works as expected

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

rm(ui, server)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            #menuItem(text = "data options",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group1", label = "group 1", 
                                         choices = c("some","check","boxes","to","choose","from") ),
                       uiOutput("sli_val1"),
                       checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group2", label = "group 2", 
                                          choices = c("another","set","of","check","boxes") ),
            #                ),
            menuItem(text = "another tab")
            )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    withProgress(message = "loading page", value=0.1, {
        ## simulate loading some data
        Sys.sleep(3)

        ## slider input
        output$sli_val1 <- renderUI({
            sliderInput(inputId = "sli_val1", 
                        label = "values", min = 0, max = 100,
                        value = c(25, 75) )
        })
        setProgress(value=1, detail="Complete")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when I move the `uiOutput` inside a `menuItem( )`, the output no longer renders:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(text = "data options",
                     checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group1", label = "group 1", 
                                        choices = c("some","check","boxes","to","choose","from") ),
                     uiOutput("sli_val1"),
                     checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group2", label = "group 2", 
                                        choices = c("another","set","of","check","boxes") )
                             ),
            menuItem(text = "another tab")
            )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
)
```

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430813/using-uioutput-in-menusubitem-of-shinydashboard?rq=1) answer to your question?

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen - not quite: I'm not using `menuSubItem( )` so I can't define the `tabName`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, I'd change `uiOutput("sli_val1")` into `uiOutput("out_sli_val1")`, to prevent duplicated Ids.

Concerning your problem: This is an odd thing going on when Shiny runs through the document and renders/binds all possible outputs. The default action is to ignore all hidden output elements - that means not ignore completely (output "sli_val1" is bound alright), but their function is suspended, letting no children to be rendered.

So the problem is, that on initiation, this output is hidden in the subitem tree and from there on ignored.

The fix can be done by unsetting this supension behaviour by calling

```
outputOptions(output, "out_sli_val1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

But how and where? This option has to be set before you run your "data loading". But it will throw errors, if `output$out_sli_val1` has nothing assigned to it (is `NULL`). To avoid that, one can initialize an empty UI-chunk, which gets overridden on "data load".

Here is your minimal fix with 2 extra lines of code (and modified output Id):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(text = "data options", 
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group1", label = "group 1", 
                           choices = c("some","check","boxes","to","choose","from") ),
        uiOutput("out_sli_val1"),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cbg_group2", label = "group 2", 
                           choices = c("another","set","of","check","boxes") )
      ),
      menuItem(text = "another tab")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$out_sli_val1 <- renderUI({})
  outputOptions(output, "out_sli_val1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  withProgress(message = "loading page", value=0.1, {
    ## simulate loading some data
    Sys.sleep(3)

    ## slider input
    output$out_sli_val1 <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(inputId = "sli_val1", label = "values", min = 0, max = 100, value = c(25, 75) )
    })

    setProgress(value=1, detail="Complete")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Nice answer! How did you do debugging?

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen I thought I read about that hidden issue somewhere. So I startet trying to manually unbind/bind the output (costom message handler + actionbutton) and looked at the HTML if the output div would react. And surpirisingly, it did as soon as the subMenu was visible. I tried linking unbind/bind to this visibility (would have been tideous) but found this more simple approach. The empty renderUI init was a hunch.

Comment: I am not sure if this is intended behavior.

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen And I am pretty sure it's not intended.

Comment: @Symbolix Maybe you could write bug report. https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues

Comment: And I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21535587/5977215) and explanation also apply too. Thanks For your answer.