# R Shiny Dashboard - uiOutput not rendering inside tab items

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny dashboard and want to include a slider bar with a dynamic range of values. To do this I am generating the `sliderInput` on the server and displaying it with `renderUI`/`uiOuput`. In the example below this works fine if I only include the slider on one `tabPanel`. However, when I attempt to add it to a second `tabPanel` it fails to render on either.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613018/r-shiny-uioutput-not-rendering-inside-menuitem) describes a similar problem but the solution (`suspendWhenHidden = FALSE`) does not work for me. I also tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394545/usage-of-uioutput-in-multiple-menuitems-in-r-shiny-dashboard) although the issue there was somewhat different.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Demo dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Overview", tabName = "overview", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "overview",
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 6,
            tabBox(
             title = "Tab box",
             width = "100%",
             id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
             tabPanel("Tab 1",
              img(src = "test_img.jpg", height="100%", width="100%", align="center"),
              # the slider is rendered properly if only included in a single tab
              uiOutput("out_slider")
             ),
             tabPanel("Tab 2",
              img(src = "test_img.jpg", height="100%", width="100%", align="center"),
              # however, uncommenting below causes the slider to not render on *either* tab 
              #uiOutput("out_slider")
             )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  startDate <- as.Date("2019-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
  endDate <- as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
  
  # from https://stackoverflow.com/q/36613018/11434833 ... does not seem to fix problem
  # output$out_slider <- renderUI({})
  # outputOptions(output, "out_slider", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  output$out_slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider"), min = startDate, 
                max = endDate, value = endDate,timeFormat="%e %b, %y")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You cannot include the same output ID twice.

Comment: Thanks. So I would need to make two separate sliders on the server and render each?

Comment: Yes.  Or you can start modules programming...bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by YBS, there is a conflict in the ID.
Try creating modules like shown below.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

slider<-function(id){
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("out_slider"))
  )
}

sliderServer<-function(id, label, min, 
                      max , value, timeFormat="%e %b, %y"){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session){
      output$out_slider <- renderUI({
        sliderInput("slider", label , min, 
                    max, value, timeFormat="%e %b, %y")
      })
    }
  )
}


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Demo dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Overview", tabName = "overview", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "overview",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 6,
                       tabBox(
                         title = "Tab box",
                         width = "100%",
                         id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
                         tabPanel("Tab 1",
                                  img(src = "test_img.jpg", height="100%", width="100%", align="center"),
                                  # the slider is rendered properly if only included in a single tab
                                  slider("tab1")
                         ),
                         tabPanel("Tab 2",
                                  img(src = "test_img.jpg", height="100%", width="100%", align="center"),
                                  # however, uncommenting below causes the slider to not render on *either* tab 
                                  slider("tab2")
                         )
                       )
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  startDate <- as.Date("2019-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
  endDate <- as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
  
  sliderServer("tab1",label = h3("Slider"), min = as.Date("2019-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), 
               max = as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), value = as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), timeFormat="%e %b, %y")
  
  sliderServer("tab2", label = h3("Slider"), min = as.Date("2019-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), 
               max = as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), value = as.Date("2020-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), timeFormat="%e %b, %y")
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you intend to pass reactive values in the sliderServer function, please wrap it in observeEvent.

Comment: Thanks for the example of modules, Asitav. I'm unclear what doing it this way accomplishes, however, as opposed to simply duplicating the `output$out_slider <- renderUI({ ...` chunk of code  from my original example (with a different output ID). In your example you still have to call `sliderServer` twice, with unique IDs ... so what did using modules accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Nick.
That was my question too before I started using modules. Modules apparently do not add value in small applications. However consider this
1. What is inside `renderUI` you had, say 20 lines of code and 
2. You need to use call this 10 times in your application
In that case, using modules will reduce the amount of coding and effort. Moreover, you also avoid copy pasting, which is prone to error. Basically, helps in managing the complexity.
Finally, if you save your modules as separate R scripts or in a package, you can use them in other applications as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanations .... now to figure out how to get each slider to update to match when the other is changed ... simple to do normally with `updateSliderInput`, but can't get it to work when they are inside the tab items

Comment: You are welcome, Nick.
Can you share the code please? I can have a look. 
BTW, if you want to use the exact same output, why not keep one slider which is outside the tabs. May be, in a new `fluidRow` inside the box or in the box footer or outside the box?

Comment: Thanks for being willing to help. I actually figured out the issue with getting the sliders to update each other. As you mentioned, it would be more ideal to use one slider. But I want it to be a  part of the `tabBox`, and for some reason, I can't get the `uiOutput` to render if I place it outside of a `tabPanel`. Similar to my original issue, but this time it cannot be due to duplicate IDs as I am only using one.